# Installer that adds entry to GPO Startup scripts

Tags: windows, installation, nsis, gpo

I'm in the process of writing an installer using NSIS that will add an entry to the computer's GPO to run a command on system boot.

```
# From http://nsis.sourceforge.net/LGP_Startup/Shutdown_Script
!include LGPScript.nsh

Section
  SetOutPath -

  # Install all files from myprog directory into C:\Program Files\myprog
  File myprog\*

  # Copy mysystweak.bat to System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\Startup
  SetOutPath $SYSDIR\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\Startup
  File myprog\mysystweak.bat
  SetOutPath -

  # Add GPO entry to execute mysystweak.bat on startup
  ${LGPScript::Create} 'Startup' 'mysystweak.bat' '' $R1
  DetailPrint "Create startup LGP return code:$R1"

  # Write uninstaller
  Writeuninstaller "${uninstall_name}"
SectionEnd
```

Everything goes well except nothing shows up in …\Startup. The installer thinks everything worked:

```
Output folder: C:\WINDOWS\system32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\Startup
Extract: mysystweak.bat... 100%
Output folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\myprog
```

I originally tried using CopyFiles to copy the batch file from $INSTDIR into …\Startup, but got the same result.

What's going wrong here?

*related: https://serverfault.com/q/266338/2101*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a x64 system you need to disable FS redirection, without it $SYSDIR will not point to the true system32 directory:

```
!include x64.nsh

Section
...
SetOutPath $SYSDIR\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\Startup
${DisableX64FSRedirection}
File myprog\mysystweak.bat
${EnableX64FSRedirection}
...
SectionEnd
```

You can verify that this is the problem by watching the installer with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)

Comment: That is the problem and fix exactly - thank you! Why couldn't the installer have said so…

Comment: @MikeyB: How would it know? Redirection should only be disabled when you really need to since other operations (CreateShortcut etc) might have to load a dll from system32 and those dll's need to be loaded from the 32bit system32! It is basically impossible for the installer to know if your batch file is a supposed to be in the real or redirected $sysdir...

Comment: @MikeyB: Also, if the \GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\Startup path does not exist by default you might want to move the SetOutPath call inside the DisableX64FSRedirection block...